# R: Find the last dot in a string

Tags: regex, r

In R, is there a better/simpler way than the following of finding the location of the last dot in a string?

```
x <- "hello.world.123.456"
g <- gregexpr(".", x, fixed=TRUE)
loc <- g[[1]]
loc[length(loc)]  # returns 16
```

This finds all the dots in the string and then returns the last one, but it seems rather clumsy. I tried using regular expressions, but didn't get very far.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
x <- "hello.world.123.456"
g <- regexpr("\\.[^\\.]*$", x)
g
```

- `\.` matches a dot
- `[^\.]` matches everything but a dot
- `*` specifies that the previous expression (everything but a dot) may occur between 0 and unlimited times
- `$` marks the end of the string.

Taking everything together: find a dot that is followed by anything but a dot until the string ends. R requires `\` to be escaped, hence `\\` in the expression above. See [regex101.com](https://regex101.com) to experiment with regex.

Comment: a '.' matches every possible character, to match a literal '.' you need to escape it with a '\' and unfortunatly, you need to escape this '\' with another '\'. So finally your expression looks like '\\.'

Comment: @Vincent, is it there a document or a package where all the symbols and text paterns are explained in detail?

Answer (score 31):

How about a minor syntax improvement?

This will work for your literal example where the input vector is of length 1. Use escapes to get a literal "." search, and reverse the result to get the last index as the "first":

```
 rev(gregexpr("\\.", x)[[1]])[1]
```

A more proper vectorized version (in case `x` is longer than 1):

```
 sapply(gregexpr("\\.", x), function(x) rev(x)[1])
```

and another tidier option to use tail instead:

```
sapply(gregexpr("\\.", x), tail, 1)
```

Comment: 9 more to go,but all i wanted to say is: slick.

Answer (score 7):

Someone posted the following answer which I really liked, but I notice that they've deleted it:

```
regexpr("\\.[^\\.]*$", x)
```

I like it because it directly produces the desired location, without having to search through the results. The regexp is also fairly clean, which is a bit of an exception where regexps are concerned :)

Comment: yeah, that was me. I thought the previous solution worked so I deleted it. Maybe I shouldn't have :)

Answer (score 2):

There is a slick [`stri_locate_last`](https://rdrr.io/rforge/stringi/man/stri_locate_last.html) function in the `stringi` package, that can accept both literal strings and regular expressions.

To just find a dot, no regex is required, and it is as easy as

```
stringi::stri_locate_last_fixed(x, ".")[,1]
```

If you need to use this function with a regex, to find the location of the last regex match in the string, you should replace `_fixed` with `_regex`:

```
stringi::stri_locate_last_regex(x, "\\.")[,1]
```

**Note** the `.` is a special regex metacharacter and should be escaped when used in a regex to match a literal dot char.

See an [R demo online](https://tio.run/##K/r/v0LBRldBKSM1Jydfrzy/KCdFz9DIWM/E1EyJq7ikKDMvPdPKCsSIz8lPTixJjc9JLC6JT8usSE3RqNBRUNJT0ozWMYzFo7YoNT21Aqw2Jgaq@v9/AA):

```
x <- "hello.world.123.456"
stringi::stri_locate_last_fixed(x, ".")[,1]
stringi::stri_locate_last_regex(x, "\\.")[,1]
```