# replace the first N dots of a string

Tags: string, r

I hope to replace the first 14 dots of `my.string` with 14 zeroes when `region = 2`.  All other dots should be kept the way they are.

```
df.1 = read.table(text = "
  city  county  state region                        my.string reg1 reg2
   1      1        1      1    123456789012345678901234567890   1    0
   1      2        1      1    ...................34567890098   1    0
   1      1        2      1    112233..............0099887766   1    0
   1      2        2      1    ..............2020202020202020   1    0
   1      1        1      2    ..............00..............   0    1
   1      2        1      2    ..............0987654321123456   0    1
   1      1        2      2    ..............9999988888777776   0    1
   1      2        2      2    ..................555555555555   0    1
", sep = "", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df.1
```

I do not think this question has been asked here.  Sorry if it has.  Sorry also not to have spent more time looking for the solution.  A quick Google search did not turn up an answer.  I did ask a similar question here earlier: [R: removing the last three dots from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11127010/r-removing-the-last-three-dots-from-a-string)  Thank you for any help.

I should clarify that I only want to remove 14 consecutive dots at the far left of the string.  If a string begins with a number that is followed by 14 dots, then those 14 dots should remain the way they are.

Here is how `my.string` would look:

```
123456789012345678901234567890
...................34567890098
112233..............0099887766
..............2020202020202020
0000000000000000..............
000000000000000987654321123456
000000000000009999988888777776
00000000000000....555555555555
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
sub("^\\.{14}", "00000000000000", df.1$my.string )
```

For conditional replacement try:

```
> df.1[ df.1$region ==2, "mystring"] <- 
               sub("^\\.{14}", "00000000000000", df.1$my.string[ df.1$region==2] )
> df.1
  city county state region                      my.string reg1 reg2
1    1      1     1      1 123456789012345678901234567890    1    0
2    1      2     1      1 ...................34567890098    1    0
3    1      1     2      1 112233..............0099887766    1    0
4    1      2     2      1 ..............2020202020202020    1    0
5    1      1     1      2 ..............00..............    0    1
6    1      2     1      2 ..............0987654321123456    0    1
7    1      1     2      2 ..............9999988888777776    0    1
8    1      2     2      2 ..................555555555555    0    1
                        mystring
1                           <NA>
2                           <NA>
3                           <NA>
4                           <NA>
5 0000000000000000..............
6 000000000000000987654321123456
7 000000000000009999988888777776
8 00000000000000....555555555555
```

Comment: Can this be done "dynamically"? as in: pad with 14 or less zeros depending on the number of `.` matched?  maybe with `gsubfun`?

Comment: Certainly `gsubfn` is an extraordinary invention but I don't think it need that degree of firepower.

Comment: Thank you.  If I make a tiny modification to the left-hand side of the line I get exactly what I want: df.1$my.string[ df.1$region ==2] <- sub("^\\.{14}", "00000000000000", df.1$my.string[ df.1$region==2] )

Answer (score 3):

```
    gsub('^[.]{14,14}',paste(rep(0,14),collapse=''),df.1$my.string)
"123456789012345678901234567890" "00000000000000.....34567890098" "112233..............0099887766"
[4] "000000000000002020202020202020" "0000000000000000.............." "000000000000000987654321123456"
[7] "000000000000009999988888777776" "00000000000000....555555555555"
```

Answer (score 3):

dwin's answer is awesome.  here's one that's easy to understand but not nearly as spiffy

```
# restrict the substitution to only region == 2..
# then replace the 'my.string' column with..
df.1[ df.1$region == 2 , 'my.string' ] <- 

    # substitute.. (only the first instance!)
    # (use gsub for multiple instances)
    sub( 
        # fourteen dots
        '..............' , 
        # with fourteen zeroes
        '00000000000000' , 
        # in the same object (also restricted to region == 2
        df.1[ df.1$region == 2 , 'my.string' ] , 
        # and don't use regex or anything special.
        # just exactly 14 dots.
        fixed = TRUE 
    )
```

Comment: you'll wanna escape each of those dots since `.` means any character in a regular expression.

Comment: I like all of the answers, and up-voted all of them, but right now yours is my favorite because it returns the complete data set exactly the way I hoped.  I will wait until tomorrow or later to give a check-mark.

Comment: @MarkMiller dwin's answer is better.  you should accept his, not mine

Comment: This won't meet the "far left of the string" requirement - it will just replace the first occurrence of 14 dots it finds. The regexp `^` anchor is important here...

Comment: @Charles one of a few reasons i recommended markmiller accept the answer by dwin, not me.  :)  my version is easy-to-understand but clunky

Answer (score 3):

A `data.table` solution:

```
require(data.table)
dt <- data.table(df.1)

# solution:
dt[, mystring := ifelse(region == 2, sub("^[.]{14}", 
                   paste(rep(0,14), collapse=""), my.string), 
                   my.string), by=1:nrow(dt)]

#    city county state region                      my.string reg1 reg2                       mystring
# 1:    1      1     1      1 123456789012345678901234567890    1    0 123456789012345678901234567890
# 2:    1      2     1      1 ...................34567890098    1    0 ...................34567890098
# 3:    1      1     2      1 112233..............0099887766    1    0 112233..............0099887766
# 4:    1      2     2      1 ..............2020202020202020    1    0 ..............2020202020202020
# 5:    1      1     1      2 ..............00..............    0    1 0000000000000000..............
# 6:    1      2     1      2 ..............0987654321123456    0    1 000000000000000987654321123456
# 7:    1      1     2      2 ..............9999988888777776    0    1 000000000000009999988888777776
# 8:    1      2     2      2 ..................555555555555    0    1 00000000000000....555555555555
```