# Return the first occurrence of a character in a string

Tags: regex, r, string

I have been trying to extract a portion of string after the occurrence of a first `^` sign. For example, the string looks like `abc^28092015^def^1234`. I need to extract `28092015` sandwiched between the 1st two `^` signs.

So, I need to extract 8 characters from the occurrence of the 1st `^` sign. I have been trying to extract the position of the first `^` sign and then use it as an argument in the substr function.

I tried to use this:

```
x=abc^28092015^def^1234 `rev(gregexpr("\\^", x)[[1]])[1]`
```

Referring the answer discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5214677/r-find-the-last-dot-in-a-string).

But it continues to return the last position. Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: You don't need regex (even though it can be done with regex too). Just [split](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/strsplit.html) the string  by `^` and get the second element.

Answer (score 4):

I would use sub.

```
x <- "^28092015^def^1234"
sub("^.*?\\^(.*?)\\^.*", "\\1", x)
# [1] "28092015"
```

Since `^` is a special char in regex, you need to escape that in-order to match literal `^` symbols.

**or**

Do splitting on `^` and get the value of second index.

```
strsplit(x,"^", fixed=-T)[[1]][2]
# [1] "28092015"
```

**or**

You may use `gsub` aslo.

```
gsub("^.*?\\^|\\^.*", "", x, perl=T)
# [1] "28092015"
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's one option with base R:

```
x <- "abc^28092015^def^1234"
m <- regexpr("(?<=\\^)(.+?)(?=\\^)", x, perl = TRUE)
##
R> regmatches(x, m)
#[1] "28092015"
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is `stri_extract_first` from `library(stringi)`

```
library(stringi)
stri_extract_first_regex(str1, '(?<=\\^)\\d+(?=\\^)')
#[1] "28092015"
```

If it is any character between two `^`

```
stri_extract(str1, regex='(?<=\\^)[^^]+')
#[1] "28092015"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- 'abc^28092015^def^1234'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
x <- 'abc^28092015^def^1234'
library(qdapRegex)
unlist(rm_between(x, '^', '^', extract=TRUE))[1]
# [1] "28092015"
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be better if you split it using `^`. But if you still want the pattern, you can try this.

```
^\S+\^(\d+)(?=\^)
```

Then match group 1.

**OUTPUT**

```
28092015
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/dD9nR4/1)